# Convert x14Id exceljs formatting - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, excel, conditional-formatting, exceljs

I added some conditional formatting to an excel sheet using ms-excel. And printed/ copied to new sheet in exceljs as follows:

```js
if (oldSheet.conditionalFormattings) {
      oldSheet.conditionalFormattings.forEach((conditionalFormatting) => {
        console.log(conditionalFormatting);
        newSheet.addConditionalFormatting(conditionalFormatting);
      });
    }
```

this logs :

```json
{
  ref: 'G2:G7',
  rules: [
    {
      type: 'containsText',
      operator: 'containsText',
      priority: 1,
      timePeriod: undefined,
      percent: undefined,
      bottom: undefined,
      rank: undefined,
      aboveAverage: undefined,
      formulae: [Array],
      style: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

and when I open new sheet it shows conditional format correctly.

Then I do few edits on excel sheet  in ms excel then re run the excel sheet logs :

```json
{
  rules: [
    {
      type: 'containsText',
      x14Id: '{FB6921CD-5991-484A-A817-95052B69C3E1}',
      priority: 1
    }
  ],
  ref: 'G2:G6'
}
```

new sheet is corrupted and ms excel asks to recover it. Once recovered no conditional formatting are there.

So, my problem is, How can I convert **x14Id** based rule to **original rule** format which supports copy and never corrupts the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with ExcelJS might be due to differences in the representation of conditional formatting rules between Excel and the ExcelJS library. Excel's internal representation of conditional formatting rules can use unique identifiers like `x14Id` to link rules to specific features, and these identifiers may not be fully compatible with ExcelJS.

To avoid corruption when copying or exporting Excel files with conditional formatting, it's generally safer to work with more standardized and supported features of Excel. Here's a suggested approach to handle conditional formatting:

1. **Recreate the Conditional Formatting Rules:** When copying or exporting data from an Excel file that contains conditional formatting, consider recreating the conditional formatting rules using ExcelJS instead of directly copying the `x14Id`-based rules. This approach will ensure that the conditional formatting rules are generated in a way that's fully compatible with ExcelJS.
2. **Use ExcelJS-Compatible Rules:** When creating the conditional formatting rules in ExcelJS, make sure to use rule types, operators, priorities, and other attributes that are well-supported and documented in the ExcelJS library. Avoid using specialized or unique rule types that may not be fully supported.
3. **Test and Verify:** After recreating the conditional formatting rules, thoroughly test the generated Excel file to ensure that it works as expected in Excel and doesn't lead to corruption issues.
4. **Stay Updated:** Keep an eye on updates and releases of the ExcelJS library. New versions of the library may include improvements and better support for various Excel features, including conditional formatting.
5. **Report Issues:** If you encounter compatibility issues or believe there might be a bug in the ExcelJS library related to conditional formatting, consider reporting the issue to the library's maintainers. They may be able to provide guidance or address the problem in future releases.

By following these best practices and recreating the conditional formatting rules in a way that's compatible with ExcelJS, you can minimize the risk of corruption when working with Excel files in your application.